# Wordpress function to send an email

Tags: php, email, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress plugin and I was wondering if wordpress has any function in its library to send emails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the risk of sounding rude, have you tried the wordpress [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail)?

Answer (score 1):

there is a wordpress function for it:

```
wp_mail($to,$subject,$message);
```